# Hyperlink comment for hive table columns

Tags: hive

So I got the command for adding a comment/field definition for a column of a Hive table. I believe the following statement (maybe with slight modifications) does the purpose:

```
alter table abc CHANGE x x bigint [COMMENT "hello"];
```

However, I wish to add a "hyperlink" comment instead of just text so that I can show the field definitions over a web interface

Is there a way to do this?